# Tooltip on mouse hover not working on firefox in asp.net vb.net javascript but working on other browsers

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am working on asp.net vb.net and I got a task to show tooltip on hover. However it is working fine on chrome and internet explorer but it is not working on fire fox. I want it to be work on all browsers. Please suggest me according to my code may be I am doing any mistake. Code is attached below.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="paymentTrackerPage">
    <div class="gridBox summary-gridBox-style" style="padding-top: 53px;">
            <div class="gbheader">
                <div class="gbheaderLeft">
                    <div class="gbheaderMiddle">
                        <DS:DSLabel ID="DSLabel1" runat="server" Text="Payment Tracker"></DS:DSLabel></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gbheaderRightCorner"></div>
            </div>

            <div style="position: relative;">
                <div class="gbbody">
                    <div class="gbrightShadow">
                     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="masterGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true"
                          PageSize="20">
                         <Columns>
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="DEAL_NUMBER" HeaderText="Deal No.">
                                 <ItemStyle CssClass="gridRow" />
                             </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SELL_CURRENCY" HeaderText="Currency">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridRow" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AMOUNT" HeaderText="Amount">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridRow alignRight" />
                                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="alignRight amountCol"/>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payment Status">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgProcessOne" CssClass="progressImg one" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/inActiveFirst.png" onmouseover="getData(this);" onmouseout="hideData()"  />
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgProcessTwo" CssClass="progressImg two" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/inActiveMid.png"  onmouseover="getData(this);" onmouseout="hideData()" />
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgProcessThree" CssClass="progressImg three" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/inActiveMid.png"  onmouseover="getData(this);" onmouseout="hideData()" />
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgProcessFour" CssClass="progressImg four" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/inActiveLast.png"  onmouseover="getData(this);" onmouseout="hideData()" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_ONE" HeaderText="" >
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="hiddencol"/>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_TWO" HeaderText="">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="hiddencol"/>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_THREE" HeaderText="">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="hiddencol"/>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_FOUR" HeaderText="">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="hiddencol"/>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                         </Columns>
                         <HeaderStyle CssClass="tableHeader" />
                     </asp:GridView>
                     </div>
                </div>

            </div>





        <div style="width: 100%; float: left; position: relative;">
                <div class="gbfooter">
                    <div class="gbfooterMiddle">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="gbfooterRightCorner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


 </div> 



<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideData() {
        $DS('.toolTip').hide();
    }
    function getData(arg) {

        //var event = document.createEvent('Event');

        var process = arg.id;
        var Value;


        document.onmouseover = function (event) {


            var evtSource;
            if (document.all) {
                evtSource = event.srcElement;
            }
            else {
                evtSource = event.target;
            }
            //var event = event || window.event;
            event = event || window.event;

        }
        //var clientX = event.clientX;
        //var clientY = event.clientY;
        var str;
        var showTip = true;
        if (process.indexOf('imgProcessOne') > 1) {
            Value = arg.parentElement.nextSibling.textContent;
            if (Value == "N") { showTip = false; }
        }
        if (process.indexOf('imgProcessTwo') > 1) {
            Value = arg.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent;
            if (Value == "N") { showTip = false; }
        }
        if (process.indexOf('imgProcessThree') > 1) {
            Value = arg.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent;
            if (Value == "N") { showTip = false; }
        }
        if (process.indexOf('imgProcessFour') > 1) {
            Value = arg.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent;
            if (Value == "N") { showTip = false; }
        }

        if (showTip == true) {
            str = "<table class='paymentTrackerTooltip' style='background-image: url(../../../images/tooltip2.png);'><tr><td>" + Value + "</td></tr></table>";
            $DS('.toolTip .content').html(str).css('background', 'transparent').css('border', 'none');
            $DS('.toolTip').css('left', event.clientX - 40).css('top', event.clientY - 70).css('display', 'block');
            // $DS('.toolTip').css('display', 'block');

            //$DS('.toolTip .bg').css('height', Auto).css();
        }
        else { return false; }

    }
```

```
Imports Datasoft.Framework.Utility
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports Datasoft.Framework.WebContainers
Imports Datasoft.Framework.WebControls
Imports C1.Web.C1WebGrid
Imports System.IO
Imports Datasoft.Framework.WebUtilities

Partial Public Class PaymentTracker
    Inherits DSCommonPage
    Dim ws As New DSService.WS
    Private Script As New StringBuilder


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Me.FormLoadComplete()
            fillGrid()

        End If
        Me.HideMasterButtons()
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "showMasterButton", "$DS('.footerButtons').css('display','none');", True)

    End Sub
    Public Sub fillGrid()
        Dim isPostValue As String = GetResourceValue("PTProcessOne")
        Dim isPaidValue As String = GetResourceValue("PTProcessTwo")
        Dim isSettledvalue As String = GetResourceValue("PTProcessThree")
        Dim isFinishedValue As String = GetResourceValue("PTProcessFour")
        Dim dateValue As String = ""
        Dim EntName As String = ""
        Dim str As String = ""
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim extraparams As New DSParameters
        Me._formParams.extraparams = DSUtilitiesWeb.Serialize(extraparams)
        Me._formParams.WebMethod = WebMethod.GetPaymentTracker
        ds = CType(CType(DSUtilitiesWeb.DeserializeResult(ws.GetDetail(Me.DSSerializedParams)), DSResult).Value, DataSet)
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
        dt.Columns.Add("PROCESS_ONE", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("PROCESS_TWO", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("PROCESS_THREE", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("PROCESS_FOUR", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("AMOUNT", GetType(String))
        Try
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                str = ""
                row("AMOUNT") = DSUtilitiesWeb.FormatCurrency(row("SELL_ITEM_ID"), row("SELL_AMOUNT"), True)
                If row("IS_POST") = True Then
                    If DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("POST_ON")) <> "" Then
                        dateValue = DSUtilities.DateFromStringWithoutTimeInCurrentFormat(row("POST_ON"))
                    End If

                    EntName = DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("ENTITY_NAME"))
                    str = isPostValue.Replace("{Date}", dateValue).Replace("{Entity}", EntName)
                    row("PROCESS_ONE") = str
                Else
                    row("PROCESS_ONE") = "N"
                End If

                If row("IS_PAID") = True Then
                    If DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("PAID_ON")) <> "" Then
                        dateValue = DSUtilities.DateFromStringWithoutTimeInCurrentFormat(row("PAID_ON"))
                    End If
                    EntName = DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("ENTITY_NAME"))
                    str = isPaidValue.Replace("{Date}", dateValue).Replace("{Entity}", EntName)
                    row("PROCESS_TWO") = str
                Else
                    row("PROCESS_TWO") = "N"
                End If


                If row("IS_SETTLED") = True Then
                    If DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("SETTLED_ON")) <> "" Then
                        'dateValue = DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("SETTLED_ON"))
                        dateValue = DSUtilities.DateFromStringWithoutTimeInCurrentFormat(row("SETTLED_ON"))
                    End If

                    EntName = DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("ENTITY_NAME"))
                    str = isSettledvalue.Replace("{Date}", dateValue).Replace("{Entity}", EntName)
                    row("PROCESS_THREE") = str

                Else
                    row("PROCESS_THREE") = "N"
                End If

                If row("IS_FINISHED") = True Then
                    'dateValue = DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("SETTLED_ON"))
                    Dim dts As New Date
                    If DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("SETTLED_ON")) <> "" Then
                        dts = DSUtilities.DateFromStringWithoutTime(row("SETTLED_ON"))
                        dateValue = DSUtilities.DateFromStringWithoutTimeInCurrentFormat(dts.AddDays(1).ToString())
                        Dim dtNow As Date = DSUtilities.DateFromStringWithoutTimeInCurrentFormat(Date.Now)
                        If dtNow >= dts.AddDays(1) Then
                            EntName = DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("ENTITY_NAME"))
                            str = isFinishedValue.Replace("{Date}", dateValue).Replace("{Entity}", EntName)
                            row("PROCESS_FOUR") = str
                        Else
                            row("PROCESS_FOUR") = "N"
                        End If

                    Else
                        EntName = DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("ENTITY_NAME"))
                        str = isFinishedValue.Replace("{Date}", dateValue).Replace("{Entity}", EntName)
                        row("PROCESS_FOUR") = str

                    End If


                    ' dateValue = DSUtilities.GetSafeString(row("SETTLED_ON"))


                Else
                    row("PROCESS_FOUR") = "N"
                End If

            Next

            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()

        Catch e As Exception
            Response.Write(e.Message)

        End Try


    End Sub

    Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Or e.Row.RowType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim isPost As Boolean = False
            Dim isPaid As Boolean = False
            Dim isSettled As Boolean = False
            Dim isFinished As Boolean = False
            If e.Row.Cells(4).Text <> "N" Then
                isPost = True
            End If
            If e.Row.Cells(5).Text <> "N" Then
                isPaid = True
            End If
            If e.Row.Cells(6).Text <> "N" Then
                isSettled = True
            End If
            If e.Row.Cells(7).Text <> "N" Then
                isFinished = True
            End If
            'formating cells having dates
            Dim pOne As Image = e.Row.FindControl("imgProcessOne")
            Dim pTwo As Image = e.Row.FindControl("imgProcessTwo")
            Dim pThree As Image = e.Row.FindControl("imgProcessThree")
            Dim pFour As Image = e.Row.FindControl("imgProcessFour")
            If isPost Then
                pOne.ImageUrl = "~/images/activeFirst.png"
            End If
            If isPaid Then
                pTwo.ImageUrl = "~/images/activeMid.png"
            End If
            If isSettled Then
                pThree.ImageUrl = "~/images/activeMid.png"
            End If
            If isFinished Then
                pFour.CssClass = "finalized"
                pFour.ImageUrl = "~/images/activeLast.png"
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewSelectEventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanging
        fillGrid()
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
        fillGrid()
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

code.css

```
.paymentTrackerGrid th {
            width: 80px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerGrid td {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .paymentTrackerGrid .gridHeader th.first {
            display: block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding-top: 6px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerGrid .gridHeader th.last {
            width: 305px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerGrid td {
            height: 30px;
        }
        .progressBar span.progress {
            width: 70px;
            float: left;
            height: 25px;
            background-image: url("DatasoftERP_Web/images/all-backs.png");
            background-position: 0px 0px;
            background-repeat:repeat;
        }
        .paymentTrackerGrid .progressBar {
            width: 285px;
            display: table;
            margin: 0 auto;
         }
        .progress img {
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        .paymentTrackerGrid .progressBar span.progress.four {
            margin-right: 0; 
        }
        .ActiveLast {
            height: 28px!important;
            margin-top: -3px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .masterGrid thead tr th {
            width: auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .gridHeader th:first-child {
            display: block;
            padding:5px 0px 0 0px !important;
        }
        td.gridRow {
            text-align: center;
        }
        /* temp css*/

        span.progress.one.tooltip:hover span {
            display: inline;
            position: absolute;
            color: #ffffff;
            background: #999999;
            visibility: visible;
            top: 40px;
            padding: 9px 14px;
            background-position: 0 0;
            left: 296px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        span.progress.two.tooltip:hover span {
            display: inline;
            position: absolute;
            color: #ffffff;
            background: #999999;
            visibility: visible;
            top: 40px;
            padding: 9px 14px;
            background-position: 0 0;
            left: 365px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .masterGrid tr {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
        }
        span.progress.three.tooltip:hover span {
            display: inline;
            position: absolute;
            color: #ffffff;
            background: #999999;
            visibility: visible;
            top: 40px;
            padding: 9px 14px;
            background-position: 0 0;
            left: 438px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        span.progress.four.tooltip:hover span {
            display: inline;
            position: absolute;
            color: #ffffff;
            background: #999999;
            visibility: visible;
            top: 40px;
            padding:9px 14px;
            background-position: 0 0;
            left: 505px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        img#GridView1_ctl02_imgProcessOne:hover td.hiddencol.showtext1 {
            visibility:visible;
        }
        .tooltip span {
            visibility:hidden;
        }
        span.tooltiptail {
            position: absolute;
            top: 60px !important;
            background: none !important;
        }
        .showtext {
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 220px;
            padding: 20px 0 0 0 !important;
            height: 170px;
            color: #777777!important;
            left: 280px;
            margin-top: -25px;
            border: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-shadow: none !important;
            background-image: url(../../../images/tooltip1.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 4px -19px;
            z-index: 999999;
            opacity: 0.11 !important;
        }
        .progressImg:hover .showtext {
            visibility:visible !important;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .gridRow td {
            padding: 8px 4px 2px 20px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage tr.altgridRow td{
            padding: 8px 4px 2px 20px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .masterGrid tfoot {
            display: table-footer-group !important;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage div.gbrightShadow {
           padding: 10px 20px;
           width: 722px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .masterGrid tr td {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 7px 0 0;
            border: none;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage table#GridView1 {
            width:730px;
            margin: 10px auto 5px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .summary-gridBox-style {
            margin: 30px 0px 50px 30px;
            width: 750px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        .paymentTrackerTooltip td {
            font-size: 11px !important;
            padding: 3px 5px 0;
            vertical-align: top;
            }
        .alignLeft {
            text-align:left !important;
        }
        .alignRight {
            text-align:right !important;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .masterGrid tbody tr:last-child a {
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin-right: 4px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .masterGrid tr:last-child td span {
            color: green;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-decoration: underline;
            margin-right: 4px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .masterGrid tr:last-child {
            border-bottom:none !important;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage table.masterGrid th {
            background-color: #71818F;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            /* border-right: 1px solid; */
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        td.showtext {
            margin-top: -71px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage .toolTip .content {
            background: transparent !important;
            border: none !important;
            }
        table.paymentTrackerTooltip {
            width: 220px;
            background-position: -6px -20px;
            height: 72px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            text-align: center;
            padding-bottom: 13px;
        }
        .paymentTrackerPage th.alignRight.amountCol {
            padding-right: 5px !important
        }
        td.gridRow.alignRight {
            padding-right: 5px !important;
        }
        .progressImg {
            width: 60px;
            height: 20px;
        }
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with sql server? There is nothing in here sql related at all? It would also be helpful if you explained what you are trying to do.

Comment: You have provided far too much code.  You should be able to narrow down to the minimum needed to reproduce the error, then more people will be willing to invest the time to help.  Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is just an css / javascript problem, your servercode has nothing todo with browser problems. To counter this you should consider using a jquery plugin for tooltips, usually they are crossbrowser tested.

Comment: Using this code What can be alternative can anyone would like to suggest me please if possible.

Comment: Actually up till now what I understand may be I am wrong but I think it is the issue of window.event which I have used in the code. I did not find any alternative of this.  May be this is an issue. I did not get any solution so far. I have pasted full code so that I get my mistake as soon as possible.